# Enlarge <p> tag borders and background around image using css

Tags: css

Is it possible to increase paragraph borders and background around big image using css?
I have to enlarge the size of box, not scale the image.

My css is in separate file, and I do not want to touch the html code. So is it possible to do that by editing **only** css?

Here is example:

[image: Example of problem]

Everybody can find out that "Big Image Test" box should be bigger. Here is example of excepted result:

[image: Excepted result]

Now it's done by just adding `<br>`-tags. Is it possible to do this just using css.

Here is part of my css file:

```css
p {
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5%;
 }

p img {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border: 0.5em groove white;
}
```

And here is html code for "block":

```html
<h3>Big Image Test</h2>
<p>
    I have a BIG image
    <img width="500" height="500" src="qr.png" alt="image"/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your css for p tag to this:

```
p {
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5%;
    overflow:hidden;
 }
```

This is a bit counter-intuitive to me and I stumbled upon it not expecting it to work while trying to figure this out but it seems to work...
Could someone explain why specifying overflow to hidden behaves like this?!

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HLYS5/)

Answer (score 0):

You are not reserving space for floated element:

```
<p>
    I have a BIG image
    <img width="500" height="500" src="qr.png" alt="image"/>

    <div style='clear:both;'></div>

</p>
```

Comment: I am trying to do this ONLY using css in my css file. (I will edit my guestion too.)

Comment: And this only moves next box down, and don't enlarge box where image  is.